# Flutter the doctor check crashed because of Visual Studio

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, exception, encoding, utf-8

i want to install flutter but every time when i use the flutter doctor command then it crashed because of Visual Studio Exception.

```
Visual Studio - develop for Windows (the doctor check crashed)
X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know
  about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
X Exception: Bad UTF-8 encoding (U+FFFD; REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) found while decoding string: [
    {
      "instanceId": "772ff8a9",
      "installDate": "2022-05-15T08:58:24Z",
      "installationName": "VisualStudio/17.2.0+32505.173",
      "installationPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community",
      "installationVersion": "17.2.32505.173",
      "productId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community",
      "productPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe",
      "state": 4294967295,
      "isComplete": true,
      "isLaunchable": true,
      "isPrerelease": false,
      "isRebootRequired": false,
      "displayName": "Visual Studio Community 2022",
      "description": "Leistungsstarke IDE, kostenlos f�r Studenten, Open-Source-Mitwirkende und Einzelpersonen",
      "channelId": "VisualStudio.17.Release",
      "channelUri": "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/channel",
      "enginePath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual
      Studio\\Installer\\resources\\app\\ServiceHub\\Services\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service",
      "installedChannelUri": "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/channel",
      "releaseNotes": "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.2#17.2.0",
      "thirdPartyNotices": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=661288",
      "updateDate": "2022-05-15T08:58:24.7196335Z",
      "catalog": {
        "buildBranch": "d17.2",
        "buildVersion": "17.2.32505.173",
        "id": "VisualStudio/17.2.0+32505.173",
        "localBuild": "build-lab",
        "manifestName": "VisualStudio",
        "manifestType": "installer",
        "productDisplayVersion": "17.2.0",
        "productLine": "Dev17",
        "productLineVersion": "2022",
        "productMilestone": "RTW",
        "productMilestoneIsPreRelease": "False",
        "productName": "Visual Studio",
        "productPatchVersion": "0",
        "productPreReleaseMilestoneSuffix": "7.0",
        "productSemanticVersion": "17.2.0+32505.173",
        "requiredEngineVersion": "3.2.2146.50370"
      },
      "properties": {
        "campaignId": "2030:e0f42e6f-47a4-4dec-83b8-446b521c8eaf",
        "channelManifestId": "VisualStudio.17.Release/17.2.0+32505.173",
        "nickname": "",
        "setupEngineFilePath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\setup.exe"
      }
    }
  ]
  . The Flutter team would greatly appreciate if you could file a bug explaining exactly what you were doing when
  this happened:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose
  The source bytes were:
  [91, 13, 10, 32, 32, 123, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 110, 115, 116, 97, 110, 99, 101, 73, 100, 34, 58, 32,
  34, 55, 55, 50, 102, 102, 56, 97, 57, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 110, 115, 116, 97, 108, 108, 68,
  97, 116, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 50, 48, 50, 50, 45, 48, 53, 45, 49, 53, 84, 48, 56, 58, 53, 56, 58, 50, 52, 90, 34,
  44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 110, 115, 116, 97, 108, 108, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34,
  58, 32, 34, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 47, 49, 55, 46, 50, 46, 48, 43, 51, 50, 53,
  48, 53, 46, 49, 55, 51, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 110, 115, 116, 97, 108, 108, 97, 116, 105, 111,
  110, 80, 97, 116, 104, 34, 58, 32, 34, 67, 58, 92, 92, 80, 114, 111, 103, 114, 97, 109, 32, 70, 105, 108, 101,
  115, 92, 92, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 32, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 32, 83, 116, 117, 100,
  105, 111, 92, 92, 50, 48, 50, 50, 92, 92, 67, 111, 109, 109, 117, 110, 105, 116, 121, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32,
  32, 34, 105, 110, 115, 116, 97, 108, 108, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 32,
  34, 49, 55, 46, 50, 46, 51, 50, 53, 48, 53, 46, 49, 55, 51, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111,
  100, 117, 99, 116, 73, 100, 34, 58, 32, 34, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 46, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97,
  108, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 46, 80, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 46, 67, 111, 109, 109, 117, 110, 105, 116,
  121, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 80, 97, 116, 104, 34, 58, 32, 34, 67,
  58, 92, 92, 80, 114, 111, 103, 114, 97, 109, 32, 70, 105, 108, 101, 115, 92, 92, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111,
  102, 116, 32, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 32, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 92, 92, 50, 48, 50, 50, 92, 92, 67,
  111, 109, 109, 117, 110, 105, 116, 121, 92, 92, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 55, 92, 92, 73, 68, 69, 92, 92, 100,
  101, 118, 101, 110, 118, 46, 101, 120, 101, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 115, 116, 97, 116, 101, 34, 58,
  32, 52, 50, 57, 52, 57, 54, 55, 50, 57, 53, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 115, 67, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101,
  116, 101, 34, 58, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 115, 76, 97, 117, 110, 99, 104, 97,
  98, 108, 101, 34, 58, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 115, 80, 114, 101, 114, 101,
  108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 34, 58, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 115, 82, 101, 98,
  111, 111, 116, 82, 101, 113, 117, 105, 114, 101, 100, 34, 58, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32,
  32, 34, 100, 105, 115, 112, 108, 97, 121, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 32, 83,
  116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 32, 67, 111, 109, 109, 117, 110, 105, 116, 121, 32, 50, 48, 50, 50, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32,
  32, 32, 32, 34, 100, 101, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 32, 34, 76, 101, 105, 115, 116, 117,
  110, 103, 115, 115, 116, 97, 114, 107, 101, 32, 73, 68, 69, 44, 32, 107, 111, 115, 116, 101, 110, 108, 111, 115,
  32, 102, 129, 114, 32, 83, 116, 117, 100, 101, 110, 116, 101, 110, 44, 32, 79, 112, 101, 110, 45, 83, 111, 117,
  114, 99, 101, 45, 77, 105, 116, 119, 105, 114, 107, 101, 110, 100, 101, 32, 117, 110, 100, 32, 69, 105, 110, 122,
  101, 108, 112, 101, 114, 115, 111, 110, 101, 110, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 99, 104, 97, 110, 110, 101,
  108, 73, 100, 34, 58, 32, 34, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 46, 49, 55, 46, 82, 101,
  108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 99, 104, 97, 110, 110, 101, 108, 85, 114, 105, 34, 58,
  32, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 97, 107, 97, 46, 109, 115, 47, 118, 115, 47, 49, 55, 47, 114, 101,
  108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 47, 99, 104, 97, 110, 110, 101, 108, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 101, 110, 103,
  105, 110, 101, 80, 97, 116, 104, 34, 58, 32, 34, 67, 58, 92, 92, 80, 114, 111, 103, 114, 97, 109, 32, 70, 105,
  108, 101, 115, 32, 40, 120, 56, 54, 41, 92, 92, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 32, 86, 105, 115, 117,
  97, 108, 32, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 92, 92, 73, 110, 115, 116, 97, 108, 108, 101, 114, 92, 92, 114, 101,
  115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 115, 92, 92, 97, 112, 112, 92, 92, 83, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 72, 117, 98, 92,
  92, 83, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 92, 92, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 46, 86, 105, 115,
  117, 97, 108, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 46, 83, 101, 116, 117, 112, 46, 83, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 34,
  44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 110, 115, 116, 97, 108, 108, 101, 100, 67, 104, 97, 110, 110, 101, 108, 85,
  114, 105, 34, 58, 32, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 97, 107, 97, 46, 109, 115, 47, 118, 115, 47, 49,
  55, 47, 114, 101, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 47, 99, 104, 97, 110, 110, 101, 108, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34,
  114, 101, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 78, 111, 116, 101, 115, 34, 58, 32, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47,
  100, 111, 99, 115, 46, 109, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 46, 99, 111, 109, 47, 101, 110, 45, 117, 115,
  47, 118, 105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 115, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 47, 114, 101, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 115, 47, 50,
  48, 50, 50, 47, 114, 101, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 45, 110, 111, 116, 101, 115, 45, 118, 49, 55, 46, 50, 35, 49,
  55, 46, 50, 46, 48, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 116, 104, 105, 114, 100, 80, 97, 114, 116, 121, 78, 111,
  116, 105, 99, 101, 115, 34, 58, 32, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 103, 111, 46, 109, 105, 99, 114, 111,
  115, 111, 102, 116, 46, 99, 111, 109, 47, 102, 119, 108, 105, 110, 107, 47, 63, 76, 105, 110, 107, 73, 100, 61,
  54, 54, 49, 50, 56, 56, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 117, 112, 100, 97, 116, 101, 68, 97, 116, 101, 34, 58,
  32, 34, 50, 48, 50, 50, 45, 48, 53, 45, 49, 53, 84, 48, 56, 58, 53, 56, 58, 50, 52, 46, 55, 49, 57, 54, 51, 51,
  53, 90, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 99, 97, 116, 97, 108, 111, 103, 34, 58, 32, 123, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32,
  32, 32, 32, 34, 98, 117, 105, 108, 100, 66, 114, 97, 110, 99, 104, 34, 58, 32, 34, 100, 49, 55, 46, 50, 34, 44,
  13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 98, 117, 105, 108, 100, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 32, 34, 49,
  55, 46, 50, 46, 51, 50, 53, 48, 53, 46, 49, 55, 51, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 105, 100, 34, 58,
  32, 34, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 47, 49, 55, 46, 50, 46, 48, 43, 51, 50, 53, 48,
  53, 46, 49, 55, 51, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 66, 117, 105, 108, 100, 34,
  58, 32, 34, 98, 117, 105, 108, 100, 45, 108, 97, 98, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 109, 97, 110,
  105, 102, 101, 115, 116, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105,
  111, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 109, 97, 110, 105, 102, 101, 115, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58,
  32, 34, 105, 110, 115, 116, 97, 108, 108, 101, 114, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111,
  100, 117, 99, 116, 68, 105, 115, 112, 108, 97, 121, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 32, 34, 49, 55, 46,
  50, 46, 48, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 76, 105, 110, 101, 34,
  58, 32, 34, 68, 101, 118, 49, 55, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116,
  76, 105, 110, 101, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 32, 34, 50, 48, 50, 50, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32,
  32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 77, 105, 108, 101, 115, 116, 111, 110, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 82,
  84, 87, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 77, 105, 108, 101, 115, 116,
  111, 110, 101, 73, 115, 80, 114, 101, 82, 101, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 70, 97, 108, 115, 101, 34,
  44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 86,
  105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 32, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114,
  111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 80, 97, 116, 99, 104, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 32, 34, 48, 34, 44, 13,
  10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 80, 114, 101, 82, 101, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101,
  77, 105, 108, 101, 115, 116, 111, 110, 101, 83, 117, 102, 102, 105, 120, 34, 58, 32, 34, 55, 46, 48, 34, 44, 13,
  10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 83, 101, 109, 97, 110, 116, 105, 99, 86, 101,
  114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 32, 34, 49, 55, 46, 50, 46, 48, 43, 51, 50, 53, 48, 53, 46, 49, 55, 51, 34, 44,
  13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 114, 101, 113, 117, 105, 114, 101, 100, 69, 110, 103, 105, 110, 101, 86, 101,
  114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 32, 34, 51, 46, 50, 46, 50, 49, 52, 54, 46, 53, 48, 51, 55, 48, 34, 13, 10, 32,
  32, 32, 32, 125, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 105, 101, 115, 34, 58, 32,
  123, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 99, 97, 109, 112, 97, 105, 103, 110, 73, 100, 34, 58, 32, 34, 50, 48, 51,
  48, 58, 101, 48, 102, 52, 50, 101, 54, 102, 45, 52, 55, 97, 52, 45, 52, 100, 101, 99, 45, 56, 51, 98, 56, 45, 52,
  52, 54, 98, 53, 50, 49, 99, 56, 101, 97, 102, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 99, 104, 97, 110, 110,
  101, 108, 77, 97, 110, 105, 102, 101, 115, 116, 73, 100, 34, 58, 32, 34, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97, 108, 83, 116, 117,
  100, 105, 111, 46, 49, 55, 46, 82, 101, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 47, 49, 55, 46, 50, 46, 48, 43, 51, 50, 53, 48,
  53, 46, 49, 55, 51, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 110, 105, 99, 107, 110, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 32,
  34, 34, 44, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 115, 101, 116, 117, 112, 69, 110, 103, 105, 110, 101, 70, 105,
  108, 101, 80, 97, 116, 104, 34, 58, 32, 34, 67, 58, 92, 92, 80, 114, 111, 103, 114, 97, 109, 32, 70, 105, 108,
  101, 115, 32, 40, 120, 56, 54, 41, 92, 92, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 32, 86, 105, 115, 117, 97,
  108, 32, 83, 116, 117, 100, 105, 111, 92, 92, 73, 110, 115, 116, 97, 108, 108, 101, 114, 92, 92, 115, 101, 116,
  117, 112, 46, 101, 120, 101, 34, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 125, 13, 10, 32, 32, 125, 13, 10, 93, 13, 10]
```

---

i cant find a solution.
maybe anyone can describe me how to fix this problem.

I tryed to reinstall the build tools in visual studio and restart the computer but nothing is working and the problem fixes i found wasnt the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this error is happening because of Flutter's latest version. So you can download an older version like 2.10.5 there: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the solution while searching on Flutter repo issues. Looks like the cause is a bug in vswhere. The solution is to replace vswhere.exe in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` with the latest version.

The latest version can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/releases

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102451